# Biggest champion possible in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Who can become the largest champion in league of legends when affected by abilities or other effects?

Examples of Large Champions:

- Chow-gath with mulitple stacks
- Zac with high health
- Hecarim

I know that Lulu's Ult [Wild Growth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu) makes a champion even bigger, are there any other effects that can cause champion model growth?